How Do I Prevent Featured Image Caption Displaying Above And Below Image
I'm trying to add an image caption below my featured image on my single posts. I have this working, but weirdly they are also displaying above the image. I'm hoping someone can help point out the issue in my code below. Thanks for your help.
function your_thumbnail_caption($html, $post_id, $post_thumbnail_id, $size, $attr){
    if (is_single()){
        $attachment =& get_post($post_thumbnail_id);

        if ($attachment->post_excerpt || $attachment->post_content) {
            $html .= '<p class="thumbcaption">';

            if ($attachment->post_excerpt) {
                $html .= '<span class="captitle">'.$attachment->post_excerpt.'</span></p>';
            }
            //$html .= '<a href="'.$attachment->post_content.'">Link To Asset</a></p>';
        }

    
    }
    return $html;
}

add_action('post_thumbnail_html', 'your_thumbnail_caption', null, 5);


I just tried with your code and it works fine. I don't see any caption displaying above image.
There can be different code that might be creating a problem.

Thanks I think there was some weird kind of injection happening in the theme I found this morning. Basically whoever created this envato theme has a seperate banner for mobile which is fine. However the desktop markup is still displaying in the source code so it was doubling up the caption. Even though the desktop banner is set to conditionally not display. Very odd. Now I spotted the problem I've resolved it lol. Thought I was going nuts. Thank you for your time, much appreciated.
